# MVC Partial View rendering as full view in its div

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

Having a lot of problems at the moment. We have written a web application using asp.net mvc 2 as well as telerik mvc extensions. In this case we have a problem with the tab strip control.

I have a link that is meant to load a partial view. This partial view contains a telerik tab strip. Unfortunately, when the link is clicked in IE7 and IE8, instead of refreshing the contents as it should (as it does in other browsers), it instead for some reason displays the whole page, within the partial view section.

I have a screenshot here:

[image: A view of the entire page being loaded again into a div where there should be only a partial view of tab contents here.]

Any Ideas? I've been working on this problem for days and would appreciate any help whatsoever that I can get on this.

FYI there appears to be no javascript errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you click at link, does it load view through ajax or regular redirection occurs?

Comment: are you having the same problem in all browser. can't really get it from the question.

Answer (score 0):

your partial view is not generated as partial view but as full view

your normal page has code such as this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Admin.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
```

and your **partial view** has code as this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<NudaJeFuc.Areas.Admin.Models.AEventCategoryModel>" %>
```

Check it...